# Passing Type/class as argument and accessing static properties, constructors etc

Tags: generics, dart

I'm fairly new to dart, so I'm still trying to figure out all of it's nuances. One thing I'm trying to do, just based on circumstances is to pass a class/type as an argument to a function so that I can access some static methods and properties.

Here's an example:

```dart
class WithStatic {
  static final test = 'wwww';
}

void main() {
  print(WithStatic.test);
  test(WithStatic);
}


void test(dynamic cls){
  // throws error Class '_Type' has no instance getter 'test'
  print(cls.test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in Dart.
Static members can only be accessed directly on the actual class, never on a variable. It doesn't matter whether you use a type variable (`<T>`) or a variable holding a `Type` object, neither provides access to a static member.

If you need need to provide delayed access to a static member, you need to pass a function

```
class WithStatic {
  static final test = 'wwww';
}

void main() {
  print(WithStatic.test);
  test(() => WithStatic.test);
}

void test(dynamic testGetter()){
  print(cls.testGetter());
}
```

Comment: Yea this would be pretty much the same thing I'm doing now, was just trying to to make some code more dry, thanks for the info though!